# What is the variance of the sum of a random sample of random variables?

Tags: random-variables, variance

Suppose we have a high-dimensional vector $\mathbf{u}\in\mathbb{R}^m$, which is drawn from a multivariate normal distribution $\mathbf{u}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{\mu}, \mathbf{\Sigma})$. To approximate the mean of the elements of $\mathbf{u}$ ($\bar{\mathbf{u}} = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m u_i$), we can sample $n<m$ elements of $\mathbf{u}$, sum them up, and then divide the sum by the number of samples $n$:

$$\bar{\mathbf{u}} \approx \hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i\in\text{sample}} u_i.$$

We can expect the approximate mean $\hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}}$ to change if we sample a different set of $n$ elements. What is the variance of the approximate means?

Example:

$$\mathbf{u} = [1, 2, 3]^T$$

The mean of the elements of $\mathbf{u}$ is $\bar{\mathbf{u}} = \frac{1}{3}(1+2+3) = 2$. We can approximate $\bar{\mathbf{u}}$ by sampling just two elements of $\mathbf{u}$:

$$\hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}} = \frac{1}{2}(1+2)=1.5$$

We can sample a different set of elements:

$$\hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}} = \frac{1}{2}(1+3)=2$$

We are looking for the variance of $\hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}}$, where $\mathbf{u}$ is a high-dimensional vector drawn from a multivariate normal distribution, $\bar{\mathbf{u}}$ is the mean of the elements of $\mathbf{u}$, and $\hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}}$ is an estimate of $\bar{\mathbf{u}}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Apparently OP is looking for the variance of $\tau = \frac{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol u}{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1}$, where $\boldsymbol u$ is a sample of a $m$-variate normal distribution with mean $\boldsymbol\mu$ and variance-covariance $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ and $\boldsymbol 1$ is a vector of $m$ ones.

Let $$A = \left\{ \boldsymbol x\in\boldsymbol\{0,1\}^m : \sum_{i=1}^m\boldsymbol x_i = n\right\},$$ where $n<m$ is known. We can assume that each vector is equally likely with probability $\frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$. We may also assume that $\boldsymbol x$ and $\boldsymbol u$ are independent.

Let's investigate the conditional mean and the conditional variance first. The conditional mean is given by $$\operatorname{E}[\tau\mid\boldsymbol x] =  \operatorname{E}\left[\frac{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol u}{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1}\mid\boldsymbol x\right] = \operatorname{E}\left[(\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1)^{-1}\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol u\mid\boldsymbol x\right] = (\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1)^{-1}\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol\mu = \frac{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol\mu}{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1}.$$ The conditional variance is given by $$\operatorname{Var}[\tau\mid\boldsymbol x] = \operatorname{Var}\left[\frac{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol u}{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1}\mid\boldsymbol x\right] = \operatorname{Var}\left[(\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1)^{-1}\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol u\mid\boldsymbol x\right] = (\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1)^{-1}\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol\Sigma\boldsymbol x(\boldsymbol 1'\boldsymbol x)^{-1} = \frac{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol\Sigma\boldsymbol x}{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol J\boldsymbol x}$$ with $\boldsymbol J = \boldsymbol 1\boldsymbol 1'$ being an $m\times m$ matrix of ones.

Now it remains to compute $$\operatorname{Var}[\tau] = \operatorname{Var}\big[\operatorname E[\tau\mid\boldsymbol x]\big] + \operatorname E\big[\operatorname{Var}[\tau\mid\boldsymbol x]\big].$$ We have that $$\operatorname{Var}\big[\operatorname E[\tau\mid\boldsymbol x]\big] = \boldsymbol\mu'\operatorname{Var}[(\boldsymbol 1'\boldsymbol x)^{-1}\boldsymbol x]\boldsymbol\mu$$ and $$\operatorname E\big[\operatorname{Var}[\tau\mid\boldsymbol x]\big] = \operatorname E[(\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol J\boldsymbol x)^{-1}(\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol\Sigma\boldsymbol x)].$$ However, it seems impossible to obtain closed form expressions for the exact values...

Comment: $\hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}}$ is not an estimator of $\mathbf{\mu}$. Suppose we draw a vector $\mathbf{u}$ from the multivariate normal distribution. We would like to estimate the mean of the elements in that vector. We can do that by sampling $n$ elements of the vector $\mathbf{u}$ and then average them.

Comment: I just added an example to the question.

Comment: The question is still not clear to provide a definite answer. You have $\boldsymbol u$ sampled from $\mathcal N(\boldsymbol\mu,\boldsymbol\Sigma)$. Then I assume you consider another random variable $\boldsymbol x$ sampled from a categorial distribution (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_distribution). The elements of $\boldsymbol x$ are either 0 or 1. Your question then is "what is the variance of $\frac{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol u}{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1_n}$?" ($\boldsymbol 1_n$ is a vector of $n$ ones).

Comment: For example, let's assume $n = 3$, and samples are $\boldsymbol u = (0.1, -0.2, 0.05)$ and $\boldsymbol x = (1, 0, 1)$. Then $\frac{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol u}{\boldsymbol x'\boldsymbol 1_n} = \frac{0.1 + 0.05}{1 + 1} = \frac{0.15}{2} = 0.075$.

Comment: In your example, $m=3$ is the dimension of vector $\mathbf{u}$, and $n=2$ is the number of $1$'s in vector $\mathbf{x}$. I am drawing a vector $\mathbf{u}$ from the multivariate distribution, and then I am averaging $n<m$ elements of $\mathbf{u}$. If $\mathbf{x}=(1, 1, 0)$, then $\frac{\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{u}}{\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{1}_n} = \frac{0.1 + (-0.2)}{1+1} = -0.05$. I am looking for the variance of $\frac{\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{u}}{\mathbf{x}'\mathbf{1}_n}$.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, $m = 3$ was meant. What is still not clear is whether $\boldsymbol x$ is a random sample from a categorial distribution OR is $\boldsymbol x$ a vector of length $m$ with the first $n$ elements being equal to 1 (and $n$ is a random draw from, say, a Poisson distribution)?

Comment: Then $\boldsymbol x$ cannot be from a Categorial distribution. I edited my answer (partial answer though) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking what is $\text{Var}[\mathbf{\bar{u}}]=\text{Var}\left[\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{u}_i\right]$, where $\mathbf{\bar{u}}=\hat{\pmb{\mu}}$.

Can you use the following property of variance to help solve your problem: for $a \in \mathbb{R}$, $X,Y$ independent random variables, we have $\text{Var}[aX+Y]=a^{2}\text{Var}[X]+\text{Var}[Y]$?

Comment: I am not asking what the variance of the mean is; I am asking what the variance of the mean of a random sample of random variables is. If $n=1$, then $\hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}}$ is equal to a single element of $\mathbf{u}$. If I sample a different element, $\hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}}$ would change. What is the variance of $\hat{\bar{\mathbf{u}}}$? What if I sample two elements and average them? Etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In my answer, $\mathbf{u}_1,...,\mathbf{u}_n$ are a random sample! Until they are observed, they are random variables, and so $\bar{\mathbf{u}}$ is also a random variable, from which we can only obtain properties like expectation, variance, etc.

Comment: I just added an example to the question.